# classifying text by sentence structure in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I want to be able to tell if a sentence actually makes sense in python. For example

```
Hello, how are you today? --> Correct
Hello, are today are how --> Incorrect
```

So far I have this code which does the following:

1 - Gets 20 000 sentences from the nltk.browns corpus.
2 - Mixes up the words of the last 10 000 sentences (for incorrect data)
3 - Tags all sentences using the Stanford POS Tagger

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.classify import accuracy
from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger
from nltk import pos_tag
import string
import random

PUNC = [x for x in string.punctuation] + ["''", "``"]

def download_data(target_path):
    brown_data = brown.sents()
    i = 0; n = 0
    with open(target_path, 'w') as data_file:
        while n < 20000:
            for sent in sent_tokenize(' '.join(brown_data[i])):
                updated_list = [x for x in word_tokenize(sent) if x not in PUNC]
                if n > 10000:
                    random.shuffle(updated_list)
                sent = ' '.join(updated_list) + '\n'
                if sent != '\n':
                    data_file.write(sent)
                    n += 1
                i += 1

def get_data(data_path):
    with open(data_path, 'r') as data_file:
        return [x for x in data_file.readlines()]

def parse_data(data, tagger):
    parsed_data = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i > 10000:
            parsed_data.append((tagger.tag(word_tokenize(data[i].replace('\n', ''))), False))
        else:
            parsed_data.append((tagger.tag(word_tokenize(data[i].replace('\n', ''))), True))
    random.shuffle(parsed_data)
    return parsed_data[:15000], parsed_data[15000:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_path = 'data.txt'

    stanford_jar_path = 'stanford-postagger.jar'
    stanford_model_path = 'models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger'

    tagger = StanfordPOSTagger(model_filename=stanford_model_path,
                               path_to_jar=stanford_jar_path)

    #download_data(data_path)
    all_data = get_data(data_path)
    train_data, test_data = parse_data(all_data, tagger)
```

So how can I train a classifier for example, to classify new texts as either correct or incorrect based on the data that I have provided?

If anybody has any better suggestions I am also open.

Comment: The technically right way to go about such problems naturally is to (a) train a language model from texts from the domain you are interested in (some kind of RNN/LSTM, if you want to be cutting edge work), then (b) establish an acceptable probability-cutoff against a known collection of good and bad sentences, and finally (c) use the sentence probabilities the model gives you on new, unseen sentences to separate your binary case. Similar to existing answers, you should probably first make sure any of this is worth it, though, with a quick-and-dirty bi- or tri-gram model.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at presence/absence of successions of parts of speech. Your examples can be transformed into the following POS succession sequences:

```
[('NNP', 'VBP'), ('VBP', 'NN'), ('NN', 'VBP'), ('VBP', 'WRB')] # incorrect
[('NNP', 'WRB'), ('WRB', 'VBP'), ('VBP', 'PRP'), ('PRP', 'NN')] # correct
```

If you order all possible combinations of two POSes and build a feature vector of 0s and 1s, you can use these vectors to train your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You are at the step when you need to create features for your training set. I would use 2 and 3 word n-grams as features and possibly 2 and 3 length n-grams of POS. So for instance, you would take all your sentences and find all bi/trigrams and binarize them (make them 0 if the current sentence does not contain them and 1 if it does). I would do the same for POS. Make bi/trigrams of POS and binarize those. Then you can use something like naive bayes to see if any predictive power exists.

Comment: would adding the n-gram as features and the pos-gram as features improve the accuracy over just pos-gram?

Comment: I think there would be some predictive power as 'brown fox' should appear much more frequently than 'fox brown'. There are certain combinations of words that would never appear in a sentence next to one another. Of course, you should test this empirically.

Comment: how would I binarize them? would I finish with a long string of 0's and 1's? @TedPetrou

Answer (score 0):

Consider Part-of-Speech tags is a good though but i believe considering n-gram language model should be good enough for your task. Here my assumption is, POS tags are few in numbers (36 according to [Penn Treebank](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html)), so the number of variations will be less if compared to vocabulary size of the corpus. So, POS tags might give you good performance but it may mislead your classifier as well. (my personal opinion)

You can do experiment with up to five-gram language model. All the n-grams will be the features for the classifier. Note that, higher number of n-gram will increase complexity but should result in more accuracy.

For classification, you can consider both generative and discriminative models. For generative model, you can consider Naive-Bayes and for discriminative model, you can consider either SVM or Logistic Regression. These classifiers works well in text classification tasks.